# Bootcamp Windows 10 microphone captures speakers output sound

Tags: windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp, microphone, speakers

I have a Macbook Pro 2017 15" with the latest version of MacOS High Sierra and a second partition where Bootcamp (Windows 10 latest version) is installed.

I use MacOS for work and Windows for gaming.
While gaming, I often use Discord or any other voice chat app to discuss with my friends at the same time.

I only use the built-in mic as well as the built-in speakers. No external headphones/mic.

The problem is : my friends hear through my mic, my speakers output.
For example : I'm playing a game while on discord, and they hear everything about the game (in addition to their own game sounds). Same thing if I'm watching a YouTube video.

I previously had a MSI GS60 gaming PC and I didn't have this problem.

I tried reinstalling Windows 10 / Bootamp, no success. I tried a full reinstall of MacOS + Windows 10/Bootcamp -> no success.

Every solution I find on the web doesn't work for me.

Have you got any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that whats going trought Discord is not whats captured by the mic, it looks more like stereo interface(I think thats the name) its a virtual device that windows creates. This device is the composed output of all the audio going on in windows. You should check the devices, open the audio mixer and check the menu. Also on discord double check the audio devices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, already double checked audio devices on Discord. Same for Audio devices on Windows. But via Bootcamp, I don't have (or didn't find it) an audio mixer or any app like that like Realtek Audio where you can adjust a lot of things related to audio.

Answer (score -1):

Well. The sound from the speakers is captured by the microphone so they cn hear it. Option 1: You can get headphones. Option 2 : Turn off your sound.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It isn't really helpful to suggest turning off the sound, especially since this is an otherwise correctable problem.